# How do I rename a column whilst doing a Room migration

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to do a migration using room and rename the column name.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
private val MIGRATION_FROM_3_TO_4 = {
    object : Migration(3, 4) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Contacts RENAME Name TO contact_name")
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE People RENAME Name TO person_name")
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Name": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE Contacts RENAME Name TO contact_name.
```

Answer (score 2):

You might get a lot of crash if you're supporting Android version 10 and below as `RENAME COLUMN` wasn't implemented at the time.

The safest way to do your operation is to make a copy of the database into a new one and rename the table. Here is the link that explains the procedure https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight error, the syntax to rename a column in SQLite is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN column_name TO new_column_name
```

The mistake was in `RENAME` which should be `RENAME COLUMN`.